# BFS (breadth first search) adjacency matrix C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue

I'm trying to learn BFS (breadth first search) with adjacency matrix.

What I tried:

- didn't really know what BFS was at all so I learned the concept & pseudocode
- tried looking at examples
- tried implementing with pointer to an array version below

Objective:

- want to make sure I'm doing BFS correctly using pointer to an array matrix

Graph Class for adjacency matrix:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

class Graph {
private:
    bool** adjMatrix;
    int numVertices;
    bool* visited;
public:
    //constructor
    Graph(int numVertices) {
        this->numVertices = numVertices;
        adjMatrix = new bool*[numVertices];
        for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
            adjMatrix[i] = new bool[numVertices];
            for(int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++)
                adjMatrix[i][j] = false;
        }

        visited[numVertices]; //init visited array


    }

    //member function
    void BFS(int sp) {
        //make a queue of type int
        queue<int> Q;

        //make bool visited array & mark all positions unvisited
        for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
            visited[i] = false;

        //push sp into queue
        Q.push(sp);

        //mark sp as visited
        visited[sp] = true;

        //while queue isn't empty
        while(!Q.empty()) {

            //make temp node
            int temp = Q.front();

            //pop temp node
            Q.pop();

            //use loop & check if it has children
            int rows =  sizeof adjMatrix / sizeof adjMatrix[0]; //get row size
            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { //check neighboring nodes
                if(!visited[i] && adjMatrix[sp][i] == true) {
                    Q.push(i); //if so push them into queue
                    visited[i] = true; //mark children as visited
                }
            }
        }

    }



};
```

Comment: what appears to be the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if there is a problem. I think it might be inside the while loop

Comment: I meant, what is the question? is something not working right? did you try compiling and running it?

Comment: More to the point, you never asked a *question*. Regardless, I have absolutely no doubt that `sizeof adjMatrix / sizeof adjMatrix[0]` is wrong. `adjMatrix` is a pointer-to-pointer (to `bool`, but that isn't really relevant right now), so `sizeof adjMatrix / sizeof adjMatrix[0]` will be `1` *always*. Pretty sure `numVerticies` will be entering this picture instead, assuming your pointer array is indeed tha wide across all rows.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Its telling me that temp is unused variable and I'm trying to use it like this example: https://imgur.com/a/lgxK89C. But I dont know how

Comment: If you're not sure what's going on, a good first step to fixing it is to step through the code in a debugger.

Comment: also I am not sure how I would use some test cases to see if its working properly. Can anyone help with that?

Comment: that image is just your code. Also, what you described is probably a warning at best unless you used a flag like `-Werror` to compile. (if you are using gcc). I meant what happens when you actually run the program? do you have any basic test cases?

Comment: "Its telling me that temp is unused variable" - in your post (not in comments) please include verbatim every warning and error from your compile or link or build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, since you didn't attach your error log or test case output consider the below implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <cstdlib>

// using namespace std;   Don't do this. Good CPP production code uses separate namespaces 

const int BUFFER_CLEAR_VALUE = 999;

class Graph {
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<bool> > adj_mat;

public:
    //constructor
    Graph() {
        std::cout << "Enter vertex num" << std::endl;
        int num_vertices;
        std::cin >> num_vertices;
        while (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cout << "Enter a valid num" << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(BUFFER_CLEAR_VALUE, '\n');
            std::cin >> num_vertices;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < num_vertices; i++) {
            std::vector<bool> temp;
            temp.resize(num_vertices);
            adj_mat.push_back(temp);
        }
    }

    // member fn
    void initialize() {
        for (int i = 0; i < adj_mat.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < adj_mat[0].size(); j++) {
                char choice;
                do {
                    std::cout << "Enter adj mat value for [y/n] " << i << ":" << j << std::endl;
                    std::cin >> choice;
                    if (choice == 'y') {
                        adj_mat[i][j] = true;
                    } else {
                        adj_mat[i][j] = false;
                    }

                    if (std::cin.fail() || (choice!='y' && choice!='n' )) {
                        std::cout << "enter a valid value please!!" << std::endl;
                        std::cin.clear();
                        std::cin.ignore(BUFFER_CLEAR_VALUE,'\n');
                    }
                } while( std::cin.fail() || (choice!='y' && choice!='n' ));
            }
        }
    }

    // member fn
    void showMatrix() {
        std::cout << std::endl << "Adjacency Matrix" << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < adj_mat.size(); i ++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < adj_mat[i].size(); j++) {
                std::cout << adj_mat[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // member fn
    void breadthFirstSearch(int start_point, int end_point) {
        std::queue<int> vertex_queue;
        std::set<int> visited_vertices;
        vertex_queue.push(start_point);

        while(!vertex_queue.empty()) {
            // Get next vertex
            int current_vertex = vertex_queue.front();
            vertex_queue.pop();

            // Make note of current visit
            visited_vertices.insert(current_vertex);
            std::cout << "Looking at " << current_vertex << std::endl;

            for (int j = 0; j < adj_mat[current_vertex].size(); j++) {
                if (adj_mat[current_vertex][j]) {
                    if (j == end_point) {
                        std::cout << "Found it " << j << std::endl;
                        return;
                    } else if (!(visited_vertices.find(j) != visited_vertices.end())) {
                        vertex_queue.push(j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Could not find it!" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    Graph g;
    g.initialize();
    g.showMatrix();
    g.breadthFirstSearch(0, 1);
    g.breadthFirstSearch(0, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Some points

- This is C++, why not use `vector` etc that handle stuff like memory for you instead? (if this is not what you want you haven't indicated so)
- They key idead behind a BFS is

  - Look at all the neighbors of the current node, start processing the neighbors of the neighbors
  - only process a node if you haven't before
- The way you are doing it nothing is next to anything. The matrix only has `false`. Did you meant to change this at some point?
- Your size calculations are wrong, they operate only on the pointers!
- You don;t have a valid termination criterion. What are you searching for with BFS? You also need to know when to stop the search. and report what happened
- What I've changed

  - Used cpp's std containers instead
  - Removed usage of `using namespace std;`
  - provided a very basic test case in `main`
  - added methods to initialize and print the matrix

Running the code I shared above for a graph like this

[image: Simple Graph]

```
$ ./Adjacency                       
Enter vertex num                             
5                                            
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 0:0            
y                                            
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 0:1            
y                                            
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 0:2            
n                                            
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 0:3            
n                                            
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 0:4            
n                                            
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 1:0            
y                                            
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 1:1            
y                                            
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 1:2            
y                                            
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 1:3            
y                                            
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 1:4            
n                                            
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 2:0            
n                                            
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 2:1            
y                                            
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 2:2
y
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 2:3
n
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 2:4
n
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 3:0
n
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 3:1
y
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 3:2
n
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 3:3
y
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 3:4
n
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 4:0
n
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 4:1
n
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 4:2
n
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 4:3
n
Enter adj mat value for [y/n] 4:4
y

Adjacency Matrix
1       1       0       0       0
1       1       1       1       0
0       1       1       0       0
0       1       0       1       0
0       0       0       0       1
Looking at 0
Found it 1
Looking at 0
Looking at 1
Looking at 2
Looking at 3
Could not find it!
```

Suggested possible improvements

1. Abstract the functionality better, right now `Graph` is a god class
2. Don't gather input for inputs in the adjacency matrix where column = row
3. Extrapolate values of the matrix based on previous values, eg: if 1 is next to 2 then you know that 2 is next to 1
4. handle input getting better, I have forgotten the clean way to `cin` stuff

#### If you insist on pointers to arrays all you ned to do is change the constructor and `.size()` invocations.